# Converting integer to string inside listbox in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here's what i've came up

```
    For intGenNum = 1 To txtInput.Text
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(intGenNum)

    Next
```

and this is the output
  [image]

my question is how can i change 1,2 and 3 to *, ** and so on?

Comment: You obviously know how to use a loop to do something a number of times. All you're asking for is how to add a particular character to a `String` multiple times. You already know all you need to.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your answer but what im trying to say is when i entered "3" in the textbox, the listbox should display:

*
**
***

Comment: Yes you are misunderstand my answer. As I said, you already know how to use a loop to do something a specific number of times. Replace `lstDisplay.Items.Add(intGenNum)` with a loop that does something a specific number of times. The something to do is add an asterisk to a `String` and the number of times is `intGenNum`. Obviously you then need to add that `String` to the `ListBox`, which you also already know how to do.

Comment: Assuming I understand your goal correctly, see if this [hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim text = ""
For intGenNum = 1 To Integer.Parse(txtInput.Text)
    text = text + "*"
    lstDisplay.Items.Add(text)
Next
```

You should also have `Option Strict On` because lines like `For intGenNum = 1 To txtInput.Text` should be a syntax error to help you code better.

Comment: Instead of using a loop, why not use `StrDup(num,"*")` to create the required string of "*"? `test=StrDup(Integer.Parse(txtInput.Text),"*")` : `lstDisplay.Items.Add(text)`. Or, in one line: `lstDisplay.Items.Add(StrDup(Integer.Parse(txtInput.Text),"*"))`

Comment: @AJD - I've answered in this way because the OP appears to be a notice so I'm providing a simple answer to help him to move forward.

Comment: @AJD : Because the OP wants to create as many strings as the number he's entered in the text box, not just one. If he enters 3 he wants to create `*`, `**` and `***`. If he enters 5 he wants to create `*`, `**`, `***`, `****` and `*****` (and so on).

Comment: @VisualVincent - There is that too.

Comment: Thankyou so much this is the result ive been trying to achive. can you please explain it to me if you dont mind?

Comment: @VisualVincent - Yes, but that simply means a loop `For I = 1 to Integer.Parse(TxtInput.Text)` : `StrDup(I,"*")  & " "` : `Next I`. Only 1 loop instead two. And removing the extra space at the end if that is important.

Comment: btw the instruction is to create a program (like this) using loop method

Comment: @IanAngeloLacson - which result - Enigmativity or mine?

Comment: @AJD - If you have an answer can you post it as such?

Comment: @IanAngeloLacson - I'll put some explanation in a little later when I have more time.

Comment: @AJD Enigmativity's result because that is the result im trying to achieve. you can explain yours to me if you dont mind, for my better understanding of the subject. thanks!

Comment: @AJD : Enigmativity is only using one loop, what are you talking about?? `StrDup()` (which by the way is an outdated VB6 function) internally uses loops, so your solution is more expensive than Enigmativity's. He also don't need spaces as he adds these strings as ListBox items.

Comment: @VisualVincent: From a readability perspective - only one loop.

Comment: @AJD : I still don't understand the point you're trying to make... **He IS only using ONE loop**.

Comment: @VisualVincent: but to achieve the changing number of stars, there is a loop to create the substring and a loop to increase the number of stars each substring.

Comment: @VisualVincent: `StrDup` is a quick answer, happy to use whatever is the latest version. See my answer below - with added textbox validation as a bonus..

Comment: @AJD : Are we discussing the same answer? **Enigmativity** is only using _**one**_ loop. Both internally and externally. Simple string concatenation (`text = text + "*"`) **is not** looping. This solution is the fastest, not `StrDup()`.

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't think we are discussing the same answer. For the input "3", the code in this answer gives "***". As I seeit,  the desired result is "* ** ***". The Comment code does some funny things. "<star><star><star>" and "<star> <star><star> <star><star><star>" respectively.

Comment: @AJD : No, this answer gives three outputs: `*`, `**`, `***`, like the OP wants. Try it yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWjnGr

Comment: @VisualVincent: OK, I missed the bit about adding inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list like:

Class

```
 Public Class listofObject
        Private num As String
        Public Property Number() As String
            Get
                Return num
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                num = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

Form_load

```
 Dim lst As New List(Of listofObject)()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstDisplay.HorizontalScrollbar = True
    End Sub
```

Button_Click

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim res As listofObject = New listofObject()
    lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
    lst.Clear()
    Try
        If Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text) Then
            For m As Integer = 0 To Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
                lst.Add(New listofObject() With {.Number = m})
            Next

            Dim result As String = String.Empty
            Dim ctr As Integer = 1

            Dim im As Integer = 1
            If lst.Count > 0 Then
                For Each num In lst
                    If lst.Count > 1 Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To num.Number - 1
                            result += "*"
                        Next
                        If im > 1 Then
                            result += ","
                        End If
                        im += 1
                    Else
                            For i As Integer = 0 To num.Number - 1
                            result += "*"
                        Next
                        'result += num.Number.ToString()
                    End If
                Next
                If lst.Count > 1 Then
                    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1)
                End If
                lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(result)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Input is not a number")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Result looks like:

Input is `5` for example

```
*,**,***,****,*****
```

Accept number only.

Comment: Can use `TextBox_Change` or `TextBox_KeyDown` to validate the input and enable/disable the `Button1`. Much better than throwing an exception (control the errors you expect and leave the exceptions to the  ...ummm... exceptions).

Comment: Instead of using a loop, why not use `StrDup(num,"*")` to create the required string of "*"?

Comment: thankyou for the answer but this is pretty complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For a form like you have: `TextBox1`, `ListBox1`, `Button1`.

```
Public Class Form2


    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Not (e.KeyChar >= "0" And e.KeyChar <= "9") Then
            e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tNum As Integer 'Long - Integer required for StrDup
        Dim tStr As String = ""
        If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
            tNum = CInt(TextBox1.Text)  ' could throw an exception if too long for Integer type
        Else
            tNum = 0
        End If

        For iterator = 1 To tNum
            tStr = tStr & StrDup(iterator, "*") & " "
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Trim(tStr))

    End Sub
End Class
```

`TextBox1_KeyPress` ensures that you only get digits (i.e. whole positive integer numbers). This reduces the error checking when trying to convert the string to a number.

The code you are really seeking is in the `Button1_Click` event handler.

`Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0` is an error check to ensure that something is returned (which we will know will only consist of digits because our earlier validation). An option is to check if `IsNumeric`.

The next loop takes the empty string `tStr` and adds the ever increasing number of "*" followed by a space.

`ListBox1.Items.Add(Trim(tStr))` uses the `Trim` command to remove the extra space at the end, and then adds the collection of "*" to the list box.

Based on a comment below - if the desired result is "*", "**" and "***" on separate lines, instead of "* ** ***", then the `Button1_Click` function is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tNum As Integer 'Long - Integer required for StrDup
        Dim tStr As String = ""
        If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
            tNum = CInt(TextBox1.Text)  ' could throw an exception if too long for Integer type
        Else
            tNum = 0
        End If

        For iterator = 1 To tNum
            tStr = StrDup(iterator, "*")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Trim(tStr))
        Next

    End Sub
```

Simple change: The `ListBox1.Add` goes inside the loop instead of outside it, and the `tStr` no longer adds to itself (nor needs the space).